# I would like to open a URL in a WebView from within a TextSpan

Tags: url, flutter, webview, textspan

Here is My Code.

```
Center(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          //style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: 'URL IS IN HERE.COM!\n',  
              style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1, fontSize: 26.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black)
            ),
            ...
```

I would like to tap the text string ('URL IS IN HERE.COM!) and for it to open in my webview widget?

Comment: Do you already have a WebView implemented? Do you want to open the url outside the app? Do you want to open a tab  of a browser inside your app? These are all different solutions. Please add more information yo your post.

Comment: Yes, I already have a WebView Implemented in a Separate Widget. So I would like to Open the URL inside of My app using the WebView Widget. I do not wish to open Outside of the App, or any browser tab, Thank you!

Comment: Here is my WebView Widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out after a lot of reading and research, This was the best solution Using a URL Scheme.

```
               onTap: () async {
                    const url = "https:www.example.com";
                  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                      await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
                } else {
                      throw "Could not launch $url";
                  }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use recognizer property of textspan and for open url in browser you can use this https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

**Widget**

```
TextSpan(text: 'Non touchable. ', children: [
  new TextSpan(
    text: 'Tap here.',
    recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () => {
      _launchURL();
    },
  )
])
```

**Method**

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not wish to use a Browser or Browser tab using the url_launcher. It is my intention is to use the WebView I have already Implemented as a separate widget and open it inside of my app. Using the Text String as a Clickable 'URL'..!

Comment: My WebView Stateful Widget Code is Below...!

Comment: I would like to Open the WebView instead of the Web Browser..??.